# Помогите разобраться с запросом jquery не приходят данные и не срабатывает проверка

Tags: php, jquery

создаю список зон

```
<select name="shipping_zone" id="shipping_zone">
  <option value="0">- выберите область -</option>
  <?php foreach ($zones as $zone) { ?>
  <?php if(!empty($zone['id_area'])){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $zone['id_area'] ?>" ><?php echo $zone['name']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

после выбора зоны хочу подгрузить хтмл через Ajax

```
$("#shipping_zone").change(function () {
  var zone = parseInt($("#shipping_zone").val());
  console.log(zone);
  getCodeNovaposhtaCities(zone);
});

function getCodeNovaposhtaCities(zone) { 
  var city = $("#shipping_city"); 
  $("#divregion").fadeIn("fast"); 
  city.attr("disabled", false); 
  if(zone > 0){ } 
  city.load( "order_change.tpl", {zone: zone}, ); 
}
```

но почему-то выходит null

```
public function getCodeNovaposhtaCities(){
  $zone = $_POST['zone'];
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "novaposhta_cities` WHERE Area ='". $zone. "'");
  //print_r($query);die;
  return $query->rows;
}
```

Comment: где "выходит null"? покажите, пожалуйста, код клиентской функции `getCodeNovaposhtaCities`

Comment: public function getCodeNovaposhtaCities(){
 $zone = $this->request->post['zone'];
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "novaposhta_cities` WHERE Area ='". $zone. "'");
  //print_r($query);die;
  return $query->rows;
} $zone = NULL  Которая должна приходить из выбора области,

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#shipping_zone").change(function () {
            var zone = ($("#shipping_zone").val());
            console.log(zone);
            getCodeNovaposhtaCities(zone);
        });
    });
    function getCodeNovaposhtaCities(zone){
        var city = $("#shipping_city");
            $("#divregion").fadeIn("fast");
            city.attr("disabled", false);
            if(zone > 0){
        }
        city.load(
                "order_change.tpl",
                {zone: zone},

        );
    }

Comment: Пожалуйста, помещайте код в вопрос путем его редактирования.

Comment: А что будет когда вам по гету пришлют `105; DROP TABLE novaposhta_cities`? Ну или что то поинтереснее. http://sqlmap.org/ Эта штука может вашу всю базу автоматически скачать и залить вам что то типа https://www.metasploit.com/... Почитайте про `SQL injection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/ :

> equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)

```
$zone = $_GET['zone'];
```

Comment: url куда должен ссылаться я сделал так  $.get('order_change.tpl', function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            alert('Загрузка завершена.');
        });

        $.get(
                "catalog/,model/account/order.php",
                {
                    zone: 'zone',

                },
                onAjaxSuccess
        );

        function onAjaxSuccess(data)
        {
  
            alert(data);
        } приходит такое http://test/catalog/,model/account/order.php?zone=7150812c-9b87-11de-822f-000c2965ae0e 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @РоманЮшко Пожалуйста, помещайте код в вопрос путем его редактирования.

Comment: я сделал так http://pastebin.com/mTTZVFnY в консоле мне приходит вот такое http://test/order_change.tpl?zone=71508133-9b87-11de-822f-000c2965ae0e 403 (Forbidden) в чем ошибка